# Ideas on how to strobe existing signal lights

Tags: headlight, lights, warning-light, brake-light, reverse-lights

I am looking to create a hazard strobe light effect, similar to that on construction vehicles, by using the cars existing reverse and turn signal lights.

I would to do this using Arduino. I am not sure if this is possible, but I would like to connect to the lights from the front of the car, in the same fashion a remote starter is connected, by connecting to the multi colored wires using a wiring diagram.

Is this possible, or will I need to connect directly to the light bulbs connectors? Also is it possible to do this without interfering with the cars ecu? What if the cars brake or reverse light are on, and then I turn on the strobe controller, will I mess anything up electrically?

Also, would there be a major difference between LED bulbs HIDs and halogens?

I know this is somewhat possible, as there is a product that does something like this, albeit it connects via OBD. It's called [Speed Turtle](https://www.ultrabrightlightz.com/speed-turtle-2-0-easy-flash-module/). Connecting via OBD would be better for me, but it is probably much harder to code.

Any ideas on where I should start?

Comment: I believe you'd get your best results by installing small LED lights separate from existing lights. Use bright LED's or even multiple LED's and mount them through the existing housing using the reflectors which are already in place. LED's are (in comparison to incandescent lights) nearly instant on/off. Halogens do not turn on/off fast enough to create a strobe effect. This would also ensure you're not messing with what's currently there.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I am looking for a solution that will allow me to use my existing lights/wiring as that would make the job much easier. Also, I don't want to have to drill holes in my light housings. I can though replace my halogens with LEDs if that's what it comes down to. I'm looking for the most plug and play way to do this.